# Get product ID on product compare page in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I would like to separate some attributes according to product category ID.
I am getting all the attributes on : `app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/catalog/product/compare/list.phtml` page.

I can get attribute value using

```
$this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $this->getProductAttributeValue($_item, $_attribute), $_attribute->getAttributeCode())
```

but how to get product category ID?

Answer (score 0):

How to get current product id

Try below code to get currently loaded product id:

```
$product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
```

When you don’t have access to $this, you can use Magento registry:

For categories do like this :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
    echo $_cat->getName();
}
```

Comment: I dont want product ID. I want Product category Id.

Comment: means category id for current product ?

Comment: @mehmood Rehman

yes. category ID of the products added in compare list.

Comment: Its not echo out anything.

Comment: what is the product id ?